# How to fix k8s namespace permissions in gitlab ci

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci

As I'm playing around with K8s deployment and Gitlab CI my deployment got stuck with the state `ContainerStarting`.

To reset that, I deleted the K8s namespace using `kubectl delete namespaces my-namespace`.

Now my Gitlab runner shows me

```
$ ensure_namespace
Checking namespace [MASKED]-docker-3
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "namespace"
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

I think that has something to do with RBAC and most likely Gitlab created that namespace with some arguments and permissions (but I don't know exactly when and how that happens), which are missing now because of my deletion.

Anybody got an idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi `error: the server doesn't have a resource type "namespace"` does it mean that namespace itself does not exit in the k8s?  that's strange

Comment: can you run `kubectl api-resources ` ?

Comment: You can follow these steps: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/#adding-an-existing-kubernetes-cluster or you can use `--insecure-skip-tls-verify` to authenticate every time you want to run `kubectl`. Also you can follow this tutorial https://medium.com/asl19-developers/connect-your-kubernetes-cluster-to-multiple-gitlab-projects-for-ci-cd-e922311172e3

Comment: I’m stuck with the same error.  After a failed deployment, gitlab would just “hang” trying to deploy a review app.  Tried deleting the namespace to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is removing the cluster from Gitlab (under operations/kubernetes in your repo)  and re-adding it.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to delete the namespace in Gitlab database, so gitlab would readd service account and namespace:

On the gitlab machine or task runner enter the PostgreSQL console:

```
gitlab-rails dbconsole -p
```

Then select the database:

```
\c gitlabhq_production
```

Next step is to find the namespace that was deleted:

```
SELECT id, namespace FROM clusters_kubernetes_namespaces;
```

Take the id of the namespace to delete it:

```
DELETE FROM clusters_kubernetes_namespaces WHERE id IN (6,7);
```

Now you can restart the pipeline and the namespace and service account will be readded.

Comment: Thank you, this worked a charm in recreating the secret to connect after I had removed the secret from K8s control panel.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the namespace manually caused the necessary secrets from Gitlab to get removed. It seems they get autocreated on the first ever deployment and it's impossible to repeat that process.

I had to create a new repo and push to it. Now everything works.

Answer (score 1):

From GitLab 12.6 you can simply [clear the cluster cache](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/#clearing-the-cluster-cache).

> To clear the cache:
>
> 1. Navigate to your project’s Operations > Kubernetes page, and select your cluster.
> 2. Expand the Advanced settings section.
> 3. Click Clear cluster cache.

This avoids losing secrets and potentially affecting other applications.